# Google OAuth with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, oauth-2.0, google-openid

I have a "Sign in to Google" button which hits an internal all url "/auth/google". This endpoint then sends a 302 to redirect to the proper Google Apps OAuth endpoint.

This works fine for the desktop version. But as jQueryMobile uses its own navigation scheme, it stops trying upon receiving the 302.

What can be done? Can I hook into the navigation somehow to force it to process the 302?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like setting rel="external" on the link did the trick.

Comment: This same issue was haunting me when trying to load the "Login with Google" button using Google's own external JS in a Sinatra app. Worked like a charm. Thanks!